# Draw text with custom font using ImageMagick and PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, text-rendering

I want to dynamically render text to an image with a custom font, preferably with the *option to output directly* or *save to a file*. And to *automatically set the image size according to the font/size combination*.

I can already do this with GD, but it doesn't handle fonts where characters overlay each other.

So now I'm looking to ImageMagick. I've found [an example in the docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label) that seem to do what I want. Is this possible with php_magick? Especially the part where no image size is defined :) If it is not, can I make command-line magick output the raw image, so I can pass it directly to the client with PHP?

Thanks!

---

The real question probably is: How do I convert the IM command below to PHP code using php_magick?

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -font Arial -pointsize 72 label:Anthony
```

Comment: Found out how to make im return the raw image data: `convert [..] png:-`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decided to skip the API and use the command-line interface instead.

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -font Arial -pointsize 72 label:Anthony png:-
```

This returns the raw PNG data, which we can then output to the browser. Replace `png:-` with the filename to save to a file instead.

Don't forget to use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) if you are using user input as parameters here.

Answer (score 15):

You should be able to use the [`annotateImage`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-annotateimage.php) function of the `Imagick` class to duplicate that functionality.

Here's a straight up copy-paste from [that documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-annotateimage.php):

```
<?php
/* Create some objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('black');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

/* Create text */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doesn't that set the image size to 800x75? I need the size to be automatically adjusted to the font size

Comment: How can I use custom ttf font?