# PHP function imagettftext() to write text with smileys

Tags: php, emoji, imagettftext

I am using imagettftext function to write text on image but my text contain smileys and it replace smileys to square box

Here is mycode:

```
$black = imagecolorallocate ( $main_img, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 );
$font_path = "Arial.ttf";
imagettftext ( $main_img, 14, 0, 73, 685, $black, $font_path, $text );
```

**Text Sample:**

```
test testt Hello  Those   Mega x ❤️  Graphic
```

I have tried with changing font which is "Arial Unicode" but its not solved issue.

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked if the font you are trying to use has characters for the unicode ranges you try to print?

Comment: yeah unicode range is supported by font but don't know about emoji

Comment: is it require emoji library or anything else to display?

Comment: @MarkusMüller: Do you suggest any font which support emojis for testing?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, we need to understand how emojis are implemented:

> **Apple’s PNG images (SBIX table)**
>
> Apple implemented it using a proprietary, unpublished extension of the TrueType/OpenType specification to add PNG images to a font. These PNG images are then displayed within running text. Google also implemented similar thing, but it is not compatible with Apple’s solution.
>
> **Mozilla and Adobe’s SVG (SVG table).**
>
> These two web giants got together for the most ambitious format: SVG in OpenType. Instead of mapping a Unicode char to a glyph, we map it to an SVG image. This brings us all the lovely extra’s of SVG, including gradients, embedded bitmap images and even animation. It’s already been supported in Firefox since version 26!
>
> **Microsoft COLR/CPAL**
>
> By default, the new Segoe UI Emoji font behaves like a regular TrueType/OpenType font. It has Unicode-encoded, uncolored “base glyphs”. But there are two additional tables in the font: the COLR table links additional glyphs as layers to the base glyphs and defines the order of these layers. And the CPAL (“Color Palette”) table stores one or more color palettes for the individual layers. (The different color palettes are useful for displaying the font on dark and light backgrounds.) So when there is support for this new color feature, the base glyphs will be replaced with the colored layers.
>
> **Google’s PNG images (CBDT/CBLC tables).**
>
> Google proposed an implementation which uses PNG images for the glyphs. The glyphs are simply replaced by good old images. This works fine for smaller icons, and obviously brings all the creative freedom of bitmap images, but doesn’t scale very well. Blow up a glyph big enough, and you’ll encounter blurred pixels. It’s also going to be hard, if not impossible, to change the color of the glyphs with CSS. Interesting is that they specify that there should be no GLYF table in their implementation — the table that holds the uncolored “normal” glyphs — so it looks like there’s no fallback for when this format isn’t supported. It’s already implemented in **FreeType**, which is used on Android and Linux, but a proposal for OpenType would bring this to Windows and Apple machines as well.
>
> ---
>
> Sources: [1](http://pixelambacht.nl/2014/multicolor-fonts/) and [2](http://microsoft-news.com/color-emoji-in-windows-8-1-are-more-interesting-than-you-think-could-be-the-future-of-color-fonts/)

The last approach is what we are interested in. This is because `imagefttext` is function provided by PHP GD extension. And GD internally uses FreeType library to draw text.

Emojis are supported in FreeType since version 2.5. Try executing `php -i` command to see what version of FreeType do you have. This is mine:

```
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.5.2
```

However, after trying with some sample fonts I found [here](https://github.com/googlei18n/color-emoji/tree/master/specification/examples), PHP keeps throwing warning:

```
Warning: imagefttext(): Could not set character size
```

I'm afraid that [GD library](https://github.com/libgd/libgd) doesn't support [FT_LOAD_COLOR](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_LOAD_COLOR) flag. This flag is required to have colored emojis. See FreeType changelog:

```
2013-05-23  Behdad Esfahbod  

    Add support for color embedded bitmaps (eg. color emoji).

    A new load flag, FT_LOAD_COLOR, makes FreeType load color
    embedded-bitmaps, following this draft specification

      https://color-emoji.googlecode.com/git/specification/v1.html
```

To answer your question: you can't have colored smileys using `imagefttext`. I'm sorry .

## Edit:

You can't also draw black and white emojis in GD. This is because GD supports only 1-3 multibyte UTF-8 characters. Emojis characters range belongs to 4 byte UTF-8 characters.

Source: https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/master/src/gdft.c#L341

Emojis table with multibyte UTF-8 representation: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: I dont want to use colored smileys but can i display smileys rather than hollow square?

Comment: @BhumiShah, I edited my answer. It's also impossible, until GD library is fixed.

Comment: is it possible to get emoji using imagick rather than gd function?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest You using PHP ImageMagick library. Though I didn't try it with emoji I'we encountered the same problem as yours with other Unicode characters when tried to render text with DG.

BTW migrating to IM is good idea at least because of better performance and less quirks in it.

[Here is an example that should work for You](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022355/433242)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a font with known emoji unicode characters. Like [Symbola](https://github.com/stv0g/unicode-emoji/blob/master/symbola/Symbola.ttf)

Comment: Could you provide string you try to draw?

Comment: I've been testing Symbola, and some characters are working fine, like ☕, but others not really.

I think it's just a case of trial and error to find a font with support you require

Comment: I have added sample text above.Also can you provide me demo

Answer (score 1):

Can you post which smiley's are you trying to use? It would be best if you could give us codes that you can see in windows charmap after selecting a smiley.
In Arial I have found only these smiley's: ☺☻☼♀♂♠♣♥♦♪♫♯ - they all show up without any problems. I used example from php.net

Comment: I am fetching data from instagram, so need generic solution for all emojis.can you provide me link or example you tried from php.net? Have you tried to display those smileys on image?

Comment: I tried this example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php but from what I see I can't use some symbols you posted. I think it's a font and/or encoding related problem.
Are your scripts encoded in utf-8? Is PHP working with default encoding set to utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

1. Use this to generate the colored nice looking emojis (select output .png)
   http://git.emojione.com/demos/latest/phpunicodetoimage.php#output
2. Use imagettftext and Arial.ttf for the remaining text
3. Append all the .png using Imagick::appendImages